# Windows batch file looping Wait animation during processing command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created the following batch file that makes Wait "| / -- \" animation. I want to use it during processing mysql restore database command `mysql -u %DBuser% -p %DB% < "%thefile%"` *where `thefile` is the sql dump file path*

```
@Echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
SET p=-1
set num=1
set "st[1]=| "
set "st[2]=/ "
set "st[3]=--"
set "st[4]=\ "

if /i %p% lss 0 (
set p=2
call :LOOP
call :DoSomeThing
)
:LOOP
if /i %num% lss 4 (
set /a num=num+1
) else (
set num=1
)
<nul set /P "=Wait !st[%num%]!!CR!"

TIMEOUT /T 1 >NUL
GOTO :LOOP

:DoSomeThing
TIMEOUT /T 10 >NUL
echo Doing...
```

Here, `:DoSomeThing` is for testing purposes and It should be replaced or include the mysql command. I get the problem that `:LOOP` works for ever and there is no call to `:DoSomeThing`

I tried to call `:DoSomeThing` before call `:LOOP` but the LOOP started after DoSomeThing is finished so it becomes useless! Is there any way to make the DoSomeThing or the MySQL command works in the background while the animation wait loop works too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

In order to fulfill your request it is necessary to execute *two threads*  simultanously, so one thread execute the mysql command and the other thread execute the looping wait animation. Both threads can be synchronized using a *flag file* that is created before mysql execution starts and is deleted after it ends, so the wait animation loops until the flag file is deleted.

The way to create a new thread is via `start` command, that may run a second Batch file that execute the mysql command and delete the flag file. However, in order to keep all the code in the same place, the `start` command may run *the same* Batch file (represented by `"%~F0"` in the code below). The key that allows this trick to work is a *special parameter* that indicate if the Batch file was re-executed from inside itself, so in this case the code just goto the section that execute the mysql command and delete the flag file.

```
@Echo OFF

rem If the Batch file was re-executed with the special parameter (second thread)
rem go to the section that execute the mysql command
if "%~1" equ ":DoSomething" goto %1

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set num=0
set "st[0]=| "
set "st[1]=/ "
set "st[2]=--"
set "st[3]=\ "

rem Do here anything you want before the mysql command...

echo Doing something for 10 seconds...
rem Create the flag file
echo X > DoingSomething
rem Re-start this Batch file with the special parameter
start "" /B "%~F0" :DoSomething
rem Simultaneously execute the waiting animation
call :LOOP

rem Do here anything you want after the mysql command...

rem ... and terminate
goto :EOF


:LOOP
set /a num=(num+1) %% 4
<nul set /P "=Wait !st[%num%]!!CR!"
TIMEOUT /T 1 >NUL
IF EXIST DoingSomething GOTO :LOOP
echo Ending loop
goto :EOF


:DoSomeThing
rem Place here the mysql command
TIMEOUT /T 10 >NUL
rem Delete the flag file
del DoingSomething
rem And terminate the second thread
goto :EOF
```

Comment: It seems very good solution, but I need some explanation for the code, specially, the second line to modify it to work with mysql command.

Comment: You just need to insert your mysql command below `:DoSomeThing` label, in place of `TIMEOUT /T 10 > NUL` line. Just be sure to keep the `del DoingSomething` command at end...

Comment: Actually, I'm using the MySQL command as a part of a batch to collecting data inputs from the user. In that batch I have already a label -subroutine- called `:restore` when I try to change it with code you supplied I get issues in the input. I believe that the second line of your code is the key and I just need an explanation for its code, to replace `:doSomeThing` with `:restore` without affecting inputs inside `:restore`.